# why use UIGraphicsPushContext/UIGraphicsPopContext

Tags: ios

I noticed below code in MBProgressHUD (https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    //do something
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

I am wondering that the "pushed context" is also the current context,why does the author push the context before drawing.

The comment says:

> use UIGraphicsPushContext() & UIGraphicsPopContext() to preserve caller graphics context w.r.t. items this drawRect: may set
>   (https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD/commit/06d5bf88b9afffa7142e543606917033f157ba5e)

what does it mean？

Answer (score 2):

That is a valid thing to wonder because as far as I can tell it is utterly pointless.  Here is a play-by-play of what will happen:

1. The view is marked as dirty and needs to be redrawn
2. A graphics context will be created and pushed internally for the view to draw into.
3. The author receives a pointer to that context via `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`
4. The author pushes the same context again.
5. The author does some drawing
6. The author pops the context off the stack (the same context still remains)
7. Internally, the context stack is popped once more.

The author might be under the impression that they need to avoid corrupting the current graphics context, but this is not a valid concern since an exclusive context is created each time for `drawRect`

The reason for the push and pop functions, as far as I can tell, is to encapsulate specialized contexts like the window context that is created for `drawRect`.  You can create it internally, push it onto the stack, and the outside class can receive it via `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` without needing to know about its implementation details.  The pop it when you are done.

Save and restore G state is more similar to the OpenGL use for snapping back to a previous matrix.